# About that translation of Tesniere's "Elements" - is it into English?

Tags: reference-request, syntax-trees

I saw that member Tim Osborne said he is working on a translation of [Tesniere's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucien_Tesni%C3%A8re) ["Elements"](http://www.librarything.com/work/2719884).

Is that translation to English? If so, when will the publication  be available?  Also, if any member can identify an already existing English translation of "Elements", please advise.

Comment: @Otavio, isn't this essentially a linguistics reference request, and therefore on-topic?

Comment: As far as I know, there has been no English translation yet. cf. in German 1980, in Russian in 1988. Quite telling, isn't it?

Comment: @musicallinguist Yes, you're right. Reopening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There will be an English translation of Tesniere's Elements appearing with John Benjamins later this year (2014) or early next year (2015). The translation is complete and currently in production at Benjamins. The stemmas are being added. Contracts have been signed. The matter is a done deal.

Comment: Benjamins indicates availability next month (and I have placed my order).  Thanks, Tim. Here's the link: https://benjamins.com/#catalog/books/z.185/main